# Jquery SetHeight according to window width using If / else

Tags: jquery

I spent a couple of hours trying to figure this out, but I am not making any progress. I have a container that contains a slideshow. On big screens, this container is supposed to be full-screen. I found a script to do just that.

On smaller screens the height of this container is supposed to be a third of the screen height. I tried going the if / else-route - but it is broken and the container is at height: 0.

Here is what I have so far, but it currently doesn't work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(  
function()   
{ function setHeight()  { 

if ($(window).width() > 768) { 

windowHeight = jQuery(window).innerHeight() -90;  
jQuery('.slideshows').css('min-height', windowHeight / 3);  
setHeight(); jQuery(window).resize(function() { setHeight(); });   
} 

else  
{ windowHeight = jQuery(window).innerHeight() -90;  
jQuery('.slideshows').css('min-height', windowHeight); ;} setHeight(); 
jQuery(window).resize(function() { setHeight(); }); }  
} 

);
```

I do not understand why the if/else breaks what is working otherwise - according to an online syntax validator the syntax is correct - but I guess it doesn't work this way for another reason. (I also guess this can probably be done a lot more effectively, seeing how the code is pretty much identical except for that one time the windowHeight is divided by 3.). Please help.

Changed the whole thing to this, which works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // run test on initial page load
    checkSize();

    // run test on resize of the window

    $(window).resize(checkSize);

//  $(window).resize(function(){location.reload();});
//  $(window).on('resize',function(){location.reload();});

});

//Function to the css rule

function checkSize(){
    if ($(".slideshows").css("background-color") == "transparent" ){
        // your code here

    jQuery(document).ready(function() { function setHeight() { windowHeight = jQuery(window).innerHeight(); jQuery('.slideshows').css('height', 200); }; setHeight(); jQuery(window).resize(function() { setHeight(); }); }); 
    }
     if ($(".slideshows").css("overflow") == "hidden" ){
        // your code here

    jQuery(document).ready(function() { function setHeight() { windowHeight = jQuery(window).innerHeight(); jQuery('.slideshows').css('height', windowHeight); }; setHeight(); jQuery(window).resize(function() { setHeight(); }); });
    }
    if ($(".slideshows").css("display") == "block" ){
        // your code here

    jQuery(document).ready(function() { function setHeight() { windowHeight = jQuery(window).innerHeight(); jQuery('.slideshows').css('height', 400); }; setHeight(); jQuery(window).resize(function() { setHeight(); }); });
    }
    if ($(".slideshows").css("align-content") == "center" ){
        // your code here

    jQuery(document).ready(function() { function setHeight() { windowHeight = jQuery(window).innerHeight(); jQuery('.slideshows').css('height', 500); }; setHeight(); jQuery(window).resize(function() { setHeight(); }); });
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the height of the div instead of min-height ?

Comment: We did. On it's own, that didn't change anything. We fiddled with the whole thing a bit more and got it working. I am going to post that in a second.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the min-height via changing css you also need to indicate the type of value. You have .css('min-height', value) and the value is a variable but it is just a numeric value. You need to indicate that this value is in pixels like this .css('min-height', value + 'px')

you are also missing px everywhere when setting min-height:

```
jQuery('.slideshows').css('height', 500px);
```